# hide tab bar in view with push

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have a `tabBar` + `NavigationViewController`. The Tab bar has collection view  with cells(Say ***view1***) and with cells a push seague is implemented to another view(Say ***view2***).

In ***view2*** I want to have a `navBar` but no tab bar.

I tried

`self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true`,

it worked fine for ***view2*** but when I went back to ***view1*** by **back button** the tab was still hidden( even after in ***view1*** class I added `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false` in **viewDidLoad** func).

How can i make the tab bar reappear in ***view1***?

I'm working in swift.

Answer (score 50):

[image]

> Make sure to check this option only on the ViewController whose tab
>   bar you wish to be hidden.

Thanks to [iHarshil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7755028/iharshil) for the suggestion.

Comment: Great! Nice & easy. Make sure to check this option only on the ViewController whose tab bar you wish to be hidden. Thanks :)

Answer (score 44):

In the `viewDidload` set the UIViewController [`hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/hidesBottomBarWhenPushed) to yes:

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

This way the `UINavigationController` takes care of hiding the tab bar.

Comment: I had already added this in code in "View2" class fun viewDidLoad but its not working...is there any other way

Comment: sorry..the code was written in View2 so it was not working...Now i shifted the code to view1 class and the tab gets hidden in View2 but again when i go back to view1 it doesn't get displayed..

Comment: This hides TabBar forever even after popped back to the root of navigation controller stack.

Comment: Don't added it to the ViewController1. Or you will get this hidden forever. When you instantiate ViewController2, you do it there, before you push it.
```
let vc2 = ViewController2()
vc2.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc2, animated: true)
```
Then when you pop back to V1 it will reappear.

Answer (score 27):

Use in `prepareForSegue`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.recipeName = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // Hide bottom tab bar in the detail view
        destViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25):

Bruno Fernandes's answer in Swift:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YourSegueIdentifier" {
        let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! YourViewController
        destinationController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    }
}
```

This was the answer that worked for me. Putting `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` in the `viewDidLoad` method didn't work.

Thanks Bruno!

Comment: Typo, controller should be: `destinationController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true`

Comment: I totally agree with Felipe, this will work in more scenarios. Just setting this property within viewDidLoad() won't always work. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

In my case, I use `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` before I push the destination view controller.

```
func showSecondViewController() {
  let vc = SecondViewController()
  vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: This is what worked for me too. I am working with a CollectionView with tabBar. I didn't want the tab bar on the detail view controller, so I put this line in my didSelectItemAt

Comment: Save my lots of time. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have to work with `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`. `viewDidLoad` will be called when view1 is loading (showing) the first time. If you move from view1 to view2 and back the viewDidLoad won't be called again. Therefore you have to use viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear like

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false
}
```

Put this code in your view1 controller. The `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` will be called every time navigating back to view1

Comment: It's `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false` in Swift 4

Answer (score 3):

**if you want to hide TabBarController Bottom Bar :  #Swift 3**

> In YourViewController :  in ViewDidLoad() method

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
```