# How can I hide a tabBar when I leave from current UIViewController?

Tags: swift, uikit

I try do it in willMove method but get bug when I break gesture(swipe to back VC)

```
override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
super.willMove(toParent: parent)

self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hide tab bar in view with push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26780719/hide-tab-bar-in-view-with-push)

Comment: Give some more information about what you have tried till now?

Comment: I want hide tb on other VC, not current

Comment: And I won't put this logic to other VC. I need hide and show on current VC. Show when current VC loaded and hide when current VC close.

Comment: Have you considered making your own tab bar? It's just a `UIView` at the bottom of a container view controller that you would be able to easily toggle using the container view's scroll view delegate.

Answer (score 2):

Use below method in **ViewDidLoad()** of ViewController(where you are going)

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
```

and in **ViewDidDisappear()**

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
```

Comment: Can I do it in current VC? Don't use both VC?

Comment: You can do it in current VC where you are going(Push/Pop). its mean for a specific view controller tab bar will be hidden and when you are about to leave that controller form stack then tab bar will show. if any issue please let me know

Answer (score 0):

In your current view controller:

In `viewDidDisappear`:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
```

In `ViewDidAppear`:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
```

Comment: in viewDidDisappear self.tabBarController = nil

Comment: In iOS view-controller's are arranged in stack, even if you go to next view-controller previous one stays in your stack. So if you will set `self.tabBarController = nil`, then on coming back it will not be shown again as `nil` will dealloc it from memory.

Comment: sorry I mean its value is nil. (print(self.tabBarController))